# htaccess redirect dynamic posts

Tags: redirect, htaccess

Probably not the correct fora to ask, but.. Also probably a simple question..

We are changing our site to Wordpress, and need to redirect old posts.

Previously structure: 
`http://url.com/art/12345.html`

Needs to go to 
`http://url.com/?p=12345`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this before any mod_rewrite directives:

```
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/art/(\d+).html /?p=$1
```